# How do I upload a .deb created by Debreate to my PPA?

Tags: packaging

I made a program using Qt Creator, and I made a package (.deb) using Debreate. Now I want to know how to upload this on PPA. I already created PPA on launchpad.

Comment: Did "Debreate" create the .deb itself?  Or did it just create the source package (the files and tarballs needed to build the binary .deb installer)

Comment: Debreate only took files which I've selected and it just made .deb out of them. Inside of a .deb package I can see three files: control.tar.gz  ;  data.tar.gz  ;  debian-binary

Is that ok?

Comment: nope, that's not a source package.

Comment: then how to create source package for Qt app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a source package run

```
dput ppa:your/ppa  yourpackage_0.1_source.changes
```

Replace `your/ppa` and `yourpackage_0.1` with your real data.

Comment: Does Debreate create the source package?  i'm not certain it does, hence my comment to the OP

Comment: how to create that source file, and how does it looks like, maybe I have it but don't know if that's it :))

Comment: You need to have `yourpackage_0.1_source.changes`, `yourpackage_0.1.dsc` and `yourpackage_0.1.tar.gz` or a similar file containing the actual sources. See http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/ and https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/Uploading for some more information.